# How to dynamically change app base path in a hosted wasm app?

Tags: html, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

In a WASM hosted project, I would like to change the app base path dynamically: given an appSettings.json configuration file, I would like to store the value associated to a given key in a variable, and set the `<base href="..."/>` tag with the content of this variable.

Currently, I can't do this because in an HTML file I can't get the configurations parameter.
So I see a few ways :

- use javascript
- change index.html (the file which contains the base tag) to a razor file

I searched on google and will continue, but if someone can give me advices on how to continue, it would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a JS file to the client app.

*site.js*

```
window.SetBaseHref = function (elementId, hRef) {
    var link = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if (link !== undefined) {
        link.href = hRef;
    }
    return true;
}
```

*wwwroot/appsettings.json*

```
{
  "Configuration": {
    "BaseHRef": "/blue"
  }
}
```

Reference it in *index.html* and create an `id` on `<base>`.

```
    <base href="~/" id="BlazorHRef" />

.......

    <script src="/site.js"></script>
```

###### Demo in the index page

```
@page "/"
@page "/red/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    Welcome to your new app.

<button type="button" @onclick="this.SetBaseHRef">SetHRef</button>

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
@code {

    [Inject] private IJSRuntime _js { get; set; }

    private bool _isAltHRef;

    private string _altHRef => _isAltHRef ? "/" : "/red";

    public async Task SetBaseHRef()
    {
        await this.SetBaseHref("BlazorHRef", _altHRef);
        _isAltHRef = !_isAltHRef;
    }

    public ValueTask<bool> SetBaseHref(string elementId, string hRef)
      => _js.InvokeAsync<bool>("SetBaseHref", elementId, hRef);

}
```

###### Setting it at startup in *App.razor*

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    [Inject] IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    [Inject] private IJSRuntime _js { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        var baseHRef = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Configuration:BaseHRef");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseHRef)) await this.SetBaseHref("BlazorHRef", baseHRef);
    }

    public ValueTask<bool> SetBaseHref(string elementId, string hRef)
          => _js.InvokeAsync<bool>("SetBaseHref", elementId, hRef);

}
```

You can change out most things in the header in a similar way.

Comment: hello, it nearly works but I have in my index.html some links like this : `<link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` and they are not impacted by the setBaseHref early enough, they use the default `<base href="~/" id="BlazorHRef" />` . Would you see an answer to this problem?

Comment: Mmmm - MudBlazor.  You're on your own at this point.  Mudblazor is a bit quirky with CSS.  I don't use it so can't answer your question.

Comment: yet MudBlazor is just an example, there are many other CSS files downloaded in index. html, I think the point is the href beginning : "_content/..." : this is a relative address, and the url is builded by appending to the base path the relative address : "~/_content/MudBlazor/...." etc... The problem being that at this moment the Javascript function SetBaseHref seems not to have been called. Hence a 404 error.

Comment: If the links are changing when you change the base then the only answer I have is to use the technique above to also update the links.

Comment: You cannot retrieve the site.js file before the correct base path is set. Since the js file is the thing that will set the correct base path, this solution will never work.

For the App.razor solution you have the same issue, the dlls that contain the compiled App.razor can never be retrieved until the appropriate base path is set.